# Alloy :Scope of Integers

Tags: alloy

I'm novice at Alloy (4.2) Sat Solver 
I have a problem with the scope of Integers
I want to guarentee that the age of a given person is always more than 18 years

Exemple:

```
sig Customer {age : Int }
fact f {   all c:Customer | c.age > 18  }
pred NewRule {   all c:Customer | c.age = 15  }
run NewRule for exactly 1 Customer
```

The problem is that the Integers in Alloy take only values between [-8,+7]

If I change the fact & mak c.age >0
and change the pred & make c.age =7
so the system is concistant

thinks

Comment: I found thesolution : add 8 Int to "run". Exemple : run NewRule for exactly 1 Customer, 8 Int